# Java Recursion Problem - Get Duplication When Printing

Tags: java

I need to print the different ways to get a given number with 3 x's. If I get the number 5, i need to print: 1 + 1 + 3 2 + 1 + 2 2 + 2 + 1 ... ..

The problem with my code it that I get duplication for an example: I get printed: 2 + 1 + 2 twice (and each combination should be printed once) I need to fix it without using for/while functions only recursion.

This is the code:

```
/**
 * 
 */
public class Main3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num =5;
        Solutions(num);
    }

    public static int Solutions(int num){
        if(num<3 || num>30){
            return 0;
        }
        Solutions(num,1,1,1);
        return 1;
    }

    public static boolean Solutions(int num, int x1,int x2, int x3){
        int sum = x1+x2+x3;
        if(x1<=num-2 && x2<=num-2 && x3<=num-2 && x1<=10 && x2<=10 && x3<=10 && sum <=num){  
            if (sum == num){
                System.out.println(x1+"+"+x2+"+"+x3);
            }
            return Solutions(num,x1+1,x2,x3) || Solutions(num,x1,x2+1,x3) || Solutions(num,x1,x2,x3+1);
        }
        return false;

    }

}
```

> I tried to come up with another solution but it gets into an endless loop, can someone recognize the problem at this code? (again while/for/other function but basic ones arent allowed)

```
    /**
 * 
 */
public class Main3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num =5;
        Solutions(num);
    }

    public static int Solutions(int num){
        if(num<3 || num>30){
            return 0;
        }
        int counter = 0;
        Solutions(num,1,1,1, counter);
        return 1;
    }

    public static boolean Solutions(int num, int x1,int x2, int x3, int counter){
        int sum = x1+x2+x3;
        if (sum == num){
            System.out.println(x1+"+"+x2+"+"+x3);
            counter++;
        }
        if (sum > num){
            return false;
        }
        if (x3<10 && x3<num-2){
            Solutions(num,x1,x2,x3+1,counter);
        }          
        if(x3 >= 10 || x3>=num-2){
            x3=1;
        }
        if (x2<10 && x2<num-2){
            Solutions(num,x1,x2+1,x3,counter);
        }          
        if(x2 >= 10 || x2>=num-2){
            x2=1;
        }
        if (x1<10 && x1<num-2){
            Solutions(num,x1+1,x2,x3,counter);
        } 
        if(x3 >= 11 || x3>=num-1){
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that: 
x + x + x = num (that's what means the 3 x's)
num can't be below 3 or above 30
and x can be any number between 1-10.

Comment: Can you use memoization? Basically, have a global Map containing the solutions you just explored, in order to prevent your recursive function to explore the same solution twice?

Comment: No, I cant only use recursion, if and I can make another function if that helps somehow

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by adding a [`Set<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) as the parameter. When you print a string, also put it into the set. Print a string only when it does not exist in the set.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 5;
        solution(num);
    }

    public static int solution(int num) {
        if (num < 3 || num > 30) {
            return 0;
        }
        solution(num, 1, 1, 1, new HashSet<String>());
        return 1;
    }

    public static boolean solution(int num, int x1, int x2, int x3, Set<String> result) {
        int sum = x1 + x2 + x3;
        if (x1 <= num - 2 && x2 <= num - 2 && x3 <= num - 2 && x1 <= 10 && x2 <= 10 && x3 <= 10 && sum <= num) {
            String print = x1 + "+" + x2 + "+" + x3;
            if (sum == num && !result.contains(print)) {
                result.add(print);
                System.out.println(print);
            }
            return solution(num, x1 + 1, x2, x3, result) || solution(num, x1, x2 + 1, x3, result)
                    || solution(num, x1, x2, x3 + 1, result);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
3+1+1
2+2+1
2+1+2
1+3+1
1+2+2
1+1+3
```

Alternatively, you can use `StringBuilder` to do it. In order to check if a string already exists inside a `StringBuilder`, you can convert it into `String` and then use `String#contains`.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 5;
        solution(num);
    }

    public static int solution(int num) {
        if (num < 3 || num > 30) {
            return 0;
        }
        solution(num, 1, 1, 1, new StringBuilder());
        return 1;
    }

    public static boolean solution(int num, int x1, int x2, int x3, StringBuilder result) {
        int sum = x1 + x2 + x3;
        if (x1 <= num - 2 && x2 <= num - 2 && x3 <= num - 2 && x1 <= 10 && x2 <= 10 && x3 <= 10 && sum <= num) {
            String print = x1 + "+" + x2 + "+" + x3;
            if (sum == num && !result.toString().contains(print)) {
                result.append(print);
                System.out.println(print);
            }
            return solution(num, x1 + 1, x2, x3, result) || solution(num, x1, x2 + 1, x3, result)
                    || solution(num, x1, x2, x3 + 1, result);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
3+1+1
2+2+1
2+1+2
1+3+1
1+2+2
1+1+3
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, is there a way to achieve it with the basic functions of JAVA and without importing?

Comment: @FreddyEstis - You are most welcome. I've added one more solution which does not require importing anything.

Answer (score 0):

**Create an ArrayList of the outputs, then create a loop which adds the elements to a new ArrayList only if it does not already contain them.** Then, return and print the new ArrayList. This is the key to removing duplicates.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 *
 */
public class Main3 {
    private static ArrayList<String>arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num =5;
        Solutions(num);
```

.

```
 System.out.println(removeDuplicates());
    }
```

The code above was edited to print the results of a new method, `removeDuplicates()`

```
public static int Solutions(int num){
        if(num<3 || num>30){
            return 0;
        }
        Solutions(num,1,1,1);
        return 1;
    }

    public static boolean Solutions(int num, int x1,int x2, int x3){
        int sum = x1+x2+x3;
        if(x1<=num-2 && x2<=num-2 && x3<=num-2 && x1<=10 && x2<=10 && x3<=10 && sum <=num){
            if (sum == num){
                String result = (x1+"+"+x2+"+"+x3);
```

.

```
 //System.out.println(result);
                arrayList.add(result);
```

Your code was edited above so that the results are added to a arrayList instead of the System.out.

```
}
            return Solutions(num,x1+1,x2,x3) || Solutions(num,x1,x2+1,x3) || Solutions(num,x1,x2,x3+1);
        }
        return false;
    }
    private static ArrayList<String>removeDuplicates() {
        ArrayList<String>noDuplicates = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String nums : arrayList) {
                if (!noDuplicates.contains(nums)) {
                    noDuplicates.add(nums);
                }
        }
        return noDuplicates;
    }
}
```

The output is: `[3+1+1, 2+2+1, 2+1+2, 1+3+1, 1+2+2, 1+1+3]`

Comment: As mentioned for and while functions can't be used. But thank you very much for your reply! it is much appriciated

Comment: Ok, you are welcome. Glad that it's appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

made some update to enforce each element is less than 11

```
import java.util.*; 

public class Main3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num =30;
        solver(num,num,3,new int[0]);
    }
    
    public static void solver(int total, int first, int length, int[] known)
    {
        if(total<first || first<=0 || length<=0)
            return;
        if(total==first && length==1 && first<=10)
        {
            for(int x: known)
                System.out.print(x+"+");
            System.out.println(first);
        }
        solver(total,first-1, length, known);
        
        if(first<=10)
        {
            int[] childKnown=new int[known.length+1];
            for(int p=0; p<known.length; p++)
                childKnown[p]=known[p];
            childKnown[known.length]=first;
            solver(total-first, total-first, length-1,childKnown);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you cannot even use for loop to clone array, you can cheat by using List<Integer> which can clone and bypass the for part